# How to send Stored values to a file in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to test if a large number of user login credentials work on a website, i have created this script and it will get the values from a csv and log in successfully for each user, All i need to do next is to add in some functionality to log into a file if a username and password logged in successfully. I am thinking that if i can log a parameter to a file then i can accomplish what i need to, does anyone have any ideas?

[Current Selenium Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjs7x.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium IDE is a javascript based tool. Javascript can not write to a file on computer due to security reasons.

My suggestions is to use screenshots. You may take screenshot on each login page and than check them. Or you can store results to an array, generate your own page with javascript with the list of results and make a screenshot of it.

**BUT** the best recommendation is to use programming language for this. That is much, much easer.

Comment: Thank you for such an informative reply, I'm very new to stack overflow and it seems the question wasn't structured very good, thank you once again for your reply